# Do posts you're tagged in that you hide from your timeline still show up in your friend's news feeds?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-tags

Do posts you're tagged in that you hide from your timeline still show up in your friend's news feeds?

Comment: I would expect so. You've not removed the tag, just hidden them (from your) view. That shouldn't affect what other people see. (I don't have a source I can point to, hence this is just a comment.)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the setting to control tagging it has the explanation that you're looking for. It says "Note: This only controls what's allowed on your timeline Posts you're tagged in still appear in search, news feed and other places on Facebook."

[image]

Comment: Well undoubtedly it would still appear in the feeds of the friends of whoever tagged you, so that's a bit lacking in specificity.

Comment: I read that to mean that the only place they don't show up is your timeline, everywhere else is unchanged.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would seem most likely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even if you choose to hide the post from your own timeline it will still end up showing in your friend's feeds. You can choose to remove the tag if you don't want to be associated with that post.