# What does "hide comment" mean? What happens if I choose that?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-tags

My friend tagged me in a random post and I wanted to remove the tag but unfortunately could not. I selected `"hide comment"` option but what exactly does that mean? Does that mean that the comment is now hidden from my friends so they can't see it anymore or does it mean the comment is only hidden from me?

Comment: Is this question different from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73022/do-posts-youre-tagged-in-that-you-hide-from-your-timeline-still-show-up-in-your ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Facebook's [Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/297845860255949?helpref=search&sr=1&query=hide%20comment):

> When you hide a comment from a post on your Page, the comment will only be visible to the person who wrote it and their friends.

So if your friends are also friends with the comment's poster, then they would still be able to see the comment; otherwise, they wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

That's not true; I hid a sub comment on a different post and it's still getting reactions from strangers that aren't mutual friends with the person... all hiding a comment seems to do is prevent you (the person who hides it) from seeing the comment or the emoji reactions it gets.

Answer (score 0):

In Facebook Groups it does nothing as of 2021:

1. Post in a public group.
2. Somebody comments on your post.
3. You right click and select "hide comment".

Now look at your post in your browser's incognito window
(not even logged in to Facebook.)
The comment is still visible to everybody.